# Search eclipse workspace where string not starting with

Tags: regex, eclipse

In the eclipse workspace search (CTRL+H) what regular expression could be used to find occurrences of a word that do not begin with 2 leading forward slashes (/) - or in other words, are not commented?

For example `//var_dump` and `// var_dump` is what is not to be matched, but `var_dump` is what is to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex in the file search tab would do it:

```
(?<!//)[ \t]*var_dump
```

If you only care about the first word on a line, precede it with a caret:

```
^(?<!//)[ \t]*var_dump
```

The `(?<!//)` part is a negative lookbehind - it only matches thing that do *not* have the contents of the brackets before the thing you are looking for.

However, if you are looking for variables that are not commented rather than not preceded by the specific combo "//", you might be better off using a syntax-aware search, which depends on the language used. For example, this regex will still match `/* var_dump */`, which you may or may not want to happen. A syntax-aware search would know this is commented.

If you look in the Search window, you will see a "Java Search" tab and tabs for other plugins you might have (I have "C/C++ Search" and "Git Search" for example). In these tabs, you can choose to search only for functions, variable, classes, or whatever else makes sense in that language.

A further thing you might want is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> on a word and it will list all the references to this object in your code - very useful when trying to track down what is calling your function or using your variable.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I wasn't too concerned about the syntax-aware search this time. I wish there was a shortcut like that which would search the working set instead of workspace. Thanks for the info

Comment: If you mean the reference search, you can right click and choose References -> Working Set... as well. You can also assign a key shortcut in Preferences -> General -> Keys, under "References in Working Set".

Comment: I thought that was ctrl+alt+g at a glance, that's really useful, thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+alt+g is raw text search, so searching on "myfunc" will find all instances of that text, including "myfunc1" and "//comment about myfunc". Ctrl+Shift+g only looks for code that is actually referencing that exact thing (so no comments or "myfunc1"s)

Comment: Unfortunately Ctrl+Shift+G only works for the current file and not the working set/workspace, I needed a combination. Great info, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a variable name (or the name of any other kind of Java element), you could use the Java search instead of the File search.  You don't have regular expression support, but the search knows you're looking for a variable/class name and so you don't have to worry about surrounding syntax.